# Test-ServiceBusName / Test-EventHub / Function-App

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-cmdlet

Hi i have a powershell script that can deploy some artifacts to azure. some of the artifacts are

- functionapp
- functionappservice
- eventhubnamespace / eventhubname
- storageaccount
  I used the below parameters to validate whether storage account and eventhub namespace is available or not.

  ```
  Test-AzureRmEventHubName
  Get-AzureRmStorageAccountNameAvailability
  ```

  I cannot find any other cmd-lets that does the same thing for other resources like service bus / servicebus queue etc.. 
  **Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a work around for checking existence

```
#replace the below condition with get command for the specific resource that you want to check
if(Get-AzureRmEventHub -ResourceGroupName Rgroup -Namespace testnamespace -Name testname -ea SilentlyContinue){
"not found"
}
else{
"found"
}
```

but if cmdlets like Test-AzureServiceBusName is available then it is definitely better

Comment: But this is only for event hub right ? what about the other resources

Comment: @HariHaran just replace the condition in the above snippet with the command to get the other resources (get-yourResourceName -param value) and -ea silentlycontinue at the end before the condition closing paranthesis and you will get similar results

Comment: I want to test if the name is available, not the resource .